# on page trigger conflict with jquery 1.9

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, conflict

I'm using the reveal modal plugin and have set it to load automatically on page open with a cookie activated, and it works great. It runs jquery v1.6. I have to implement it onto a page with Nivoslider which uses v1.9.

When put on the page with Nivoslider the trigger to open on page load now doesn't work anymore - but reveal on click still works - so there isn't really a conflict between 1.6 and 1.9, just it no longer opens on page load.

If I remove the link to 1.9 the trigger works again, but Nivoslider obviously doesnt. Is there a work around for this? Code below if you need to see it. Thanks...

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="popup/reveal.css"> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.min.js">/script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="popup/jquery.reveal.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="popup/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
jQuery(document).ready(function(){ 
if (jQuery.cookie('sale') != '1') { 
 jQuery('#myModal').reveal() 
    jQuery('#myModal').trigger('click'); 
    jQuery.cookie('sale', '1', { expires: 3}); } 
}); 
</script>  

<script type="text/javascript" src="slider/scripts/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="slider/jquery.nivo.slider.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function() {
$('#slider').nivoSlider({
   effect: 'fade', 
   animSpeed: 700, 
   pauseTime: 4000, 

});
});
</script>
```

Comment: Just to be safe, you should wrap your second snippet in `(function($){... your code ...})($.noConflict(true))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you loading `2 versions of jquery` try this,

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="popup/reveal.css"> 

<!-- Use only the new version only like 1.9.0 -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="slider/scripts/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="popup/jquery.reveal.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="popup/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
jQuery(document).ready(function(){ 
if (jQuery.cookie('sale') != '1') { 
 jQuery('#myModal').reveal() 
    jQuery('#myModal').trigger('click'); 
    jQuery.cookie('sale', '1', { expires: 3}); } 
}); 
</script>  

<script type="text/javascript" src="slider/jquery.nivo.slider.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {//use document ready instead of windows load function
   $('#slider').nivoSlider({
      effect: 'fade', 
      animSpeed: 700, 
      pauseTime: 4000, 
   });
});
</script>
```

**Note** if it not works the use the `jquery migrate plugin`, there are many `functions` which are removed in `jquery 1.9 version`

Comment: SOLVED! The jquery migrate plugin worked for this - thanks for suggesting it!

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recomend only using one library on a page due to the reduced performance each one provides. I would recomend trying to update the reveal plugin to work with jquery v9, or finding a more up to date plugin the achieves the same goal.

That said, if this is not viable you can use jqueries no conflict option to allow both library's to run together:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

Answer (score -1):

The .live() method has been deprecated since jQuery 1.7 and has been removed in 1.9. We recommend upgrading code to use the .on() method instead. To exactly match $('a[data-reveal-id]').live('click', function(e), for example, you can write

```
    $('a[data-reveal-id]').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var modalLocation = $(this).attr('data-reveal-id');
    $('#'+modalLocation).reveal($(this).data());
});
```

Comment: This is a direct copy/paste of the JQuery documentation, and has no explanation as to why it would resolve the OP's issue